# Fill sparse array

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm

I have a sparse array, for example:

```
rare = [[0,1], [2,3], [4,5], [7,8]]
```

I want to plot a chart with these data, each pair are point coordinates.
As you can see I don't have points for x=1, x=3 , x=5, x=6

I want to fill the array with the previous values, so for the above example I will get:

```
filled = [[0,1], [1,1], [2,3], [3,3], [4,5], [5,5], [6,5], [7,8]
```

As you can see, for calculating the y value, I simply take the last y value I used.

What is the best aproach to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Range.new(*rare.transpose.first.sort.values_at(0,-1)).inject([]){|a,i|
  a<<[i, Hash[rare][i] || a.last.last]
}
```

Step-by-step explanation:

1. `rare.transpose.first.sort.values_at(0,-1)` finds min and max `x` (`[0,7]` in your example)
2. `Range.new()` makes a range out of it (`0..7`)
3. `inject` iterates through the range and for every `x` returns pair `[x,y]`, where `y` is:

   1. `y` from input array, where defined
   2. `y` from previously evaluated pair, where not

Note: here are some other ways of finding min and max x:

```
[:min,:max].map{|m| Hash[rare].keys.send m}
rare.map{|el| el.first}.minmax # Ruby 1.9, by steenslag
```

Comment: Care to talk us through that one? I assume it'll work but it's not particularly readable :)

Comment: It fails for empty "rare". I'd say that using << with inject is kind of cheating, but it will be definitely faster.

Comment: @Glenjamin: I gave my best :) @tokland: Thanks for the bug report, and why do you think `<<` with inject is cheating? Cheating could be using `inject` where `map` is logical (as I am mapping an array to another), but I needed previous values, therefore `inject`.

Comment: @mladen: it should read "cheating", it was a pedantic note ;-) as you know "inject" is the Ruby's name for the standard FP fold/reduce/... function, and in FP you don't modify objects in-place. Of course in Ruby we do it all the time, so it's not a big deal. To be purely functional: a + [[i, Hash[rare][i] || a.last.last]].

Comment: In ruby 1.9 step 1 can be replaced with: rare.map{|el| el.first}.minmax

Comment: @tokland: True, I plead guilty for being functionally unpure. ;) @steenslag: Thanks, I didn't know about the method, updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
rare = [[0,1], [2,3], [4,5], [7,8]]

filled = rare.inject([]) do |filled, point|
  extras = if filled.empty?
             []
           else
             (filled.last[0] + 1 ... point[0]).collect do |x|
               [x, filled.last[1]]
             end
           end
  filled + extras + [point]
end

p filled
# => [[0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 3], [3, 3], [4, 5], [5, 5], [6, 5], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: note to @astropanic, my solution and Wayne's are virtually the same (only his was 4 mins faster).

Comment: @tokland, :)  I'd get out of my mind if I were you.  Take it from me: It's scary in here!

Answer (score 2):

An `inject` solution:

```
filled = rare.inject([]) do |filled_acc, (pair_x, pair_y)|
  padded_pairs = unless filled_acc.empty?    
    last_x, last_y = filled_acc.last
    (last_x+1...pair_x).map { |x| [x, last_y] }
  end || []
  filled_acc + padded_pairs + [[pair_x, pair_y]] 
end
```

More about `Enumerable#inject` and functional programming with Ruby [here](http://www.oreillynet.com/ruby/blog/2006/07/nubygems_inject_is_functional.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
irb(main):001:0> rare = [[0,1], [2,3], [4,5], [7,8]]
=> [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8]]
irb(main):002:0> r=rare.transpose
=> [[0, 2, 4, 7], [1, 3, 5, 8]]
irb(main):003:0> iv = (r[0][0]..r[0][-1]).to_a.select {|w| !r[0].include?(w) }
=> [1, 3, 5, 6]
irb(main):004:0> r[1][-1]=r[1][-2]
=> 5
irb(main):005:0> p (iv.zip(r[1]) + rare).sort
[[0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 3], [3, 3], [4, 5], [5, 5], [6, 5], [7, 8]]
=> [[0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 3], [3, 3], [4, 5], [5, 5], [6, 5], [7, 8]]
```